# How would i change this to be in a private void?

Tags: java, string, frequency, frequency-analysis

How would I change this to go into the private void?
It is currently in the public static void. The main problem is that in the private void it cant read string. I am quite new to programming so please be patient if this is quite easy to do.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FrequencyPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ccrrcdcffcghijk";
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (hashMap.containsKey(s.charAt(i))) {
                int value = hashMap.get(s.charAt(i));
                hashMap.put(s.charAt(i), ++value);
            } else {
                hashMap.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }

        Character keys[] = Arrays.copyOf(hashMap.keySet().toArray(), hashMap
                .keySet().toArray().length, Character[].class);
        Integer values[] = Arrays.copyOf(hashMap.values().toArray(), hashMap
                .values().toArray().length, Integer[].class);


        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            int x = FrequencyPrint.findmax(values);
            for (int j = 0; j < values[x]; j++) {
                System.out.print(keys[x]);
            }
            values[x] = 0;
        }

    }

    public static int findmax(Integer values[]) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] > values[max]) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to set private? findmax? the main method? the public method has always to be public.

Comment: If `main()` you "can't"; it must be `public static` for it to be usable. You can put other modifiers but then it won't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FrequencyPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrequencyPrint fP = new FrequencyPrint();
        fP.readStrings();
    }

    private void readStrings() {
        String s = "ccrrcdcffcghijk";
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (hashMap.containsKey(s.charAt(i))) {
                int value = hashMap.get(s.charAt(i));
                hashMap.put(s.charAt(i), ++value);
            } else {
                hashMap.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }

        Character keys[] = Arrays.copyOf(hashMap.keySet().toArray(), hashMap
            .keySet().toArray().length, Character[].class);
        Integer values[] = Arrays.copyOf(hashMap.values().toArray(), hashMap
            .values().toArray().length, Integer[].class);


        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            int x = this.findmax(values);
            for (int j = 0; j < values[x]; j++) {
                System.out.print(keys[x]);
            }
            values[x] = 0;
        }

    }

    private int findmax(Integer values[]) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] > values[max]) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return an int, but you are passing an Integer[] as argument. You basically have 4 options

> 1. keep the method as it is (suggested..).    Now, if you are bent upon keeping the return type as private void,  then
> 2. Create an object of FrequenceyPrint in main(), call findMax() using the object's reference, pass an Integer/object which
>      encapsulates an  int/Integer as argument . change the object
>      referenced by the  reference in findMax, your main() will get back the
>      data